# Compiling twitter bootstrap .less files into custom css file, what order should they go in?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I am currently working on a project and I want to use the twitter bootstrap directly editing the .less files. To do this I have a less compiler which simply checks if the .less files have been changed and recompiles them into my .css file which is then published to the web.

My question is, in what order should each of the .less files be compiled into my css file, I have obviously started by adding the reset, then base stuff, responsive etc and so on but wonder wonder if there is a correct order - I couldn't see any mention of this on the bootstap site and don't want to end up with things not working because the cascade is wrong. Is this even much of an issue with the bootstrap - i.e does it not do a lot of overruling previous styles.

Any help is appreciated obviously - thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only need to compile `bootstrap.less` because it imports every other file automatically.

Comment: Ah, the joy of getting bootstrap from some other source than the default, this was not included in favour of their own method - now I got it - thanks.

Comment: Does this also compile the bootstrap-responsive.css file?

Comment: @streetlight Nope, see https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/responsive.less: "Required since we compile the responsive stuff separately"